# Spider Plant can't support own weight

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, repotting

[image: Bendy stem support by sushi sticks]

I've had this spider plant for 2 years at this point. I've repotted it recently. The plant consists of 4/5 supplants, if I can count correctly. To be fair, the plant is a little bit crowded in the center so it's hard to tell really.

[image: Sushi Sticks keeping plant up straight]

The plant has been doing great overall, many pups have come from this big boy. However, recently I noticed that the plant seems to be too heavy for its own good. It was next to a window where it got some morning sun, but after reading up online, I think that might have been too much for it. In the center, the "stems" from which new leaves grow are twisted-like and new leaves are quite thin. My watering depends on how wet the soil is but it, most of the time, boils down to once a week. I fertilise once every fortnight.

[image: No leaves in the middle because they all lean to a side, no upright leaves, which I do have in one other spider plant.]

Is this fixable or do I have to give up on this beautiful plant and live with the heavy looking one?

In the first picture you can see the center shoot bending to the left, it is not growing up straight and is supported by a sushi stick in the ground. I did it with more shoots, which is visible on other pictures. Without these sticks, the center shoots would lean to one side and the center would be empty, except for long stems from where the blades of grass originate.

Comment: Add a picture of the plant please

Comment: Spider plants normally droop and hang gracefully, so this is quite unclear without a picture. They certainly don't grow "up" much, and are classic hanging-planter plans as a result.

Comment: I'll try and add a picture but it was giving me an error earlier...